# how to get results from a controller with parameters enabled

Tags: spring

This is how I get a list of `staff`.

```
public class StaffController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StaffController.class);

    @Inject
    private StaffService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listAll(@Param("branchId") Integer branchId,
                      @Param("page") Integer page,
                      @Param("rowsPerPage") Integer rowsPerPage,
                      Model model,
                      HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Staff information list page.");
        model.addAttribute("context", request.getContextPath());

        Map<String, Object> keys = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        keys.put("branchId", branchId);
        keys.put("page", page);
        keys.put("rowsPerPage", rowsPerPage);
        //List<StaffVO> list = service.listAll(1, 1, 10);
        List<StaffVO> list = service.listAll(keys);


        model.addAttribute("list", list);

        return "/staff/list";
    }
}
```

And then in JSP, I get the result like below:

```
<% List<StaffVO> list = (List<StaffVO>)request.getAttribute("list"); %>
```

Ok, great.
but where in earth should I pass parameters like `branchId`, `page` and `rowsPerPage`. So that the controller can query exactly what I want.

For now, I just ignore parameters and just query everything because `branchId`, `page`, `rowsPerPage` are all null.

And here's my StaffMapper:

```
public interface StaffMapper {

    final String SELECT_STAFF =
        "SELECT staff.id, staff_level, staff.name, cell, date_join, employment, status, allow_absence_control, branch.id as branch_id, branch.name as branch_name " +
        "FROM staff " +
        "LEFT JOIN branch " +
        "ON staff.branch_id=branch.id " +
        "WHERE branch.id=1";

    @Select(SELECT_STAFF)
    public List<StaffVO> listAll(Map<String, Object> keys) throws Exception;
}
```

SO, assume that now I have `keys` that actually has keys and values. Then, How can I insert that information into the SELECT string?

I tried `WHERE branch.id = #{keys[branchId]}` and many more but didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: So u are trying to query from your JSP?

Comment: @IvanLymar I just want to know how to pass parameters to listAll() method in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correct, you need to get data in your controller. You can achieve this by two ways:

1) `@PathVariable`

```
@RequestMapping("/foo/{bar}/{bazz}")
public String getEvent(@PathVariable Long bar,@PathVariable String bazz) {
model.addAttribute(...);
return model;
}
```

Url example:

hostname:port/foo/2/Hello

hostname:port/foo/3/Bye

Two last variables will be treated as path variables and can be used in controller.

2) `@RequestParam`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/balance", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addBalance( @RequestParam Double bar){
...
}
```

Here you need to use html form, e.g.

```
<form name="foo" action="/balance" method="post">
Add money:
  <input type="number" name="bar" /></br>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

This will put variable from < input> to request parameters. Names in input and controller should be the same.

p.s. scriptlets are not the best way to get data in JSP. I believe that it's bad to mix HTML and JAVA. You should consider using JSTL.